# SQL: Perform Mathematical Operations On Column(s) Before Applying Aggregate Function

Tags: sql

Consider a table containing following data.

| Date | Taxable_Sale | Tax_Rate | Gross_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-04 | 1000 | 5 | 1050 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2000 | 10 | 2010 |
| 2022-03-01 | 3000 | 12 | 3360 |

Now If I want to perform aggregate function on table to get total sales monthwise, I have written query like this.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date) AS month,
       SUM(Gross_Amount) AS totalSales
FROM sales_table
WHERE date between '2022-04-01' AND '2023-03-31'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

Now similarly I want to calculate sum of tax collected for the month, for which a column does not exist in the table. So my question is can I calculate the **sum of taxes collected for the month** (tax for day is Taxable_Sale * (5/100)) in the same query? How would I go about doing that? Would joins be necessary?

I've tried a few different things but unable to get the right solutions. Hence wanting to know if this is possible in single query.

Comment: Have you tried using "*Taxable_Sale*" inside another `SUM`? Maybe your attempts just need some little tweak. Consider adding the expected output to your post as well: could clarify if it's more complex than what's currently written in the description.

Comment: You can include you tax rate sum as another aggregate, you can aggregate expressions as well as columns - please include what you have tried in your question.

Comment: @lemon needed the sum of tax amount rather than taxable sale / tax rate. Thanks the answer has solved my issue.